# How do I search-and-replace base64 sub-strings in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, wordpress-theming

I have a MySQL database for a WordPress site with many pages. The popular Avada theme I am using has a feature for inserting HTML code blocks into the content area. I used this to insert many URLs throughout the site. I just migrated the site and discovered that all of the code blocks still have my old testing environment URLs, because the code blocks are base64 encoded in the database, between [fusion_code][/fusion_code] tags. The content field in the database is mostly plain text until we reach a code block, then it is encoded. It looks like this:

```
<here is lots of unencoded content and html tags>**[fusion_code]PGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdC9lc3RlZW0vY29zbWV0aWMtc3VyZ2VyeS9ib2R5L2FiZG9taW5vcGxhc3R5LXR1bW15LXR1Y2svIj4=[/fusion_code]**<here is more unencoded content and html tags>**[fusion_code]PGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdC9lc3RlZW0vY29zbWV0aWMtc3VyZ2VyeS9ib2R5L2FiZG9taW5vcGxhc3R5LXR1bW15LXR1Y2svIj4=[/fusion_code]**<here is more unencoded content and html tags etc>
```

I need a way to:

1. Search for all instances of these code blocks in the database.
2. Do a base64 decode of the content between the [fusion_code][/fusion_code] tags.
3. Replace the old testing base url with a new base url.
4. Base64 encode the result, just between the [fusion_code][/fusion_code] tags, while leaving the rest of the content untouched.

Is this possible? If so, what would the correct MySQL query to run be?

Comment: Are all the base64 encodes strings the same within a fusion code block.. the example data says it is.. In MySQL this is not really easy to do because there isnt regex replace unless you are using MySQL 8

Comment: I think they all start off the same. I thought it would be possible because they all have a clear start and end point (the [fusion_code] tags). It isn't urgent for me to know the solution to this any more, I need up doing it all manually, but it would be useful to know for the future, and I'll bet others are having thew same issue as me using Avada.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should work, I can't get it to work properly though..

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION fusion_decode(post_content LONGTEXT)
RETURNS LONGTEXT
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE code LONGTEXT;
    WHILE post_content LIKE '%[fusion_code]%' DO
        SET code = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_content, '[/fusion_code]', 1), '[fusion_code]', -1);
        SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, CONCAT('[fusion_code]', code, '[/fusion_code]'), FROM_BASE64(code));
    END WHILE;
    RETURN post_content;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```